# Running tf.mod and tf.floor_div in tensorflow in GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wanna use tf.mod and tf.floor_div for some operation in middle of my CNN network, but it seems that they can not be run in GPU, so they are passed to CPU and it causes to reduce the speed of training significantly.

For example in the following simplified code I get following error:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
  b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='b')
  c = tf.mod(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.

config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
# Runs the op.
print sess.run(c)
```

here I get this error:

> Cannot assign a device to node 'Mod': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
>        [[Node: Mod = Mod[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/device:GPU:0"](a, b)]]

I can use allow_soft_placement = True for solving this problem here, but the operation will be done in CPU.

I am running my code in ubuntu 14, python 2.7 with tensorflow 0.12.

I appreciate if anyone can help me how I can solve the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Some of op only have CPU implement, e.g. Mod, [look](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5a5a25ea3ebef623e07fb9a46419a9df377a37a5/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_op_gpu_mod.cu.cc#L22)

Comment: Is this still a thing? When I look at the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_op_gpu_mod.cu.cc#L22) it seem to be the case, but maybe I am looking in the wrong place.